# While Recording in Squish using python, how to set the application to sleep for sometime between 2 consecutive activities?

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, ui-automation, squish

I am working on an application where there are read only screens.
To test whether the data is being fetched on screen load, i want to set some wait time till the screen is ready.
I am using python to record the actions. Is there a way to check the static text on the screen and set the time ?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use 
snooze(time in s).

Example:
snooze(5)

If you want to wait for a certain object, use

waitForObject(":symbolic_name")

Example:
type(waitForObject(":Welcome.Button"), )

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more complicated if your objects are created dynamically. As my app does. In this case, you should create a while function that waits until the object exists. Here, maybe this code helps you:

```
def whileObjectIsFalse(objectID):
# objectID = be the symbolic name of your object.

    counter = 300
    objectState = object.exists(objectID)
    while objectState == False:
        objectState = object.exists(objectID)
        snooze(0.1)
        counter -= 1
        if counter == 0:
            return False
    snooze(0.2)
```

In my case, even if I use snooze(), doesn't work all the time, because in some cases i need to wait 5 seconds, in other 8 or just 2. So, presume that your object is not created and tests this for 30 seconds. 
If your object is not created until then, then the code exits with False, and you can tests this to stop script execution.

Comment: You can simplify this considerably using the [`waitFor`](http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#waitFor-function) function: `waitFor(lambda: object.exists(objectID), 30000)` .

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python, you can use time.sleep() as well